# Convert Time on ruby to month and date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible in ruby to convert this string "2011-03-31" to May 3, 2011 or just implement a method to do this?

Comment: 2011-03-31 is March 31, 2011, or did you want it to jump ahead 1 month and 4 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Date.parse("2011-03-31").strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Depending on the environment, you may have to

```
require 'date'
```

Comment: I think you want to use `%e` instead of `%d`. `%d` includes leading zeros.

Comment: Yup, you're correct @tjwallace `Date.parse("2011-03-31").strftime("%B %e, %Y")`

Answer (score 1):

```
Date.strptime("2011-03-31", "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%B %e, %Y")
```